# Get latest version of github package

Tags: github, github-package-registry

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/packages#get-a-package-version-for-an-organization The API's listed in here does not provide the API to list the latest package version, in fact it is an array if there are multiple versions. Does anyone know how can I get the latest version of the package?